# How to configure ansible host to connect to azure via a service principle

Tags: azure, ansible

I want to connect to azure via a service principle via my Ansble host (RHEL 8.1 vm) to get the list of VMs in an Azure resource group.
How do i automatically configure this ansible host.

I have installed ansible[azure] by command:
    sudo pip3 install ansible[azure]

I already have created a credential file inside .azure in the home directory.

```
$ vim ~/.azure/credential 
[default] 
subscription_id=xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx 
client_id=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx 
secret=xxxxxxxxxx 
tenant=xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
```

I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/dynamic-inventory-configure#generate-a-dynamic-inventory
to create "myazure_rm.yml"

```
---
plugin: azure_rm
include_vm_resource_groups:
  - ansible-inventory-test-rg
auth_source: auto

keyed_groups:
- prefix: tag
  key: tags
```

when i run the following i get no feedback:

```
[azureuser@vmaepansible002 ~]$ ansible all -m ping -i ./myazure_rm.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

Do i need azure cli installed on this host to complete this? Im expect not  - or am i wrong?